# How to fire a method,when we scroll down from a UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

Is there any way to  fire a method,when we scroll down from the bottom of a UIWebView ?
I have seen many answers but could not find a workable idea :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebView conforms to the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol.

The protocol defines the `scrollViewDidScroll:` (look it up [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate)) method. If you implement it and set your object as the delegate of UIWebView you should get notified if the View scrolls. You can then ask the webview for its `contentOffset` and determine whether the scroll was upwards or downwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use method `scrollViewDidScroll` of `UIScrollViewDelegate`